# Fourier transform of distributions: exercises

Tags: fourier-analysis

I was doing some exercises but I have some doubts. Here are some of the problems that I'm facing:

1. Compute the F.T. of $\mathcal{F}D^kT$, where $D^k$ is the $k$-th derivative of the distribution $T$.

I did the following steps:
let $\phi(x)\in S(\mathbb{R})$, and $\hat\phi(y)$ its F.T. :
$$
\begin{align}
(\mathcal{F}D^kT)[\phi] &=(D^kT)_{\mathcal{F}}[\phi]\\
&=(-1)^kT_{\mathcal{F}}\left[\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^k\phi\right]\\
&=(-1)^kT\left[\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^k\phi\right]
\end{align}
$$
and by the property $\mathcal{F}[(d/dx) f] = -iy\mathcal{F}[f]$:
$$
\begin{align}
(-1)^kT\left[\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^k\phi\right] &= (-1)^kT\left[(-iy)^k\mathcal{F}[\phi]\right]\\
&= (iy)^kT[\mathcal{F}[\phi]]=(iy)^k\mathcal{F}[T][\phi]
\end{align}
$$
But the right answer is: $(-iy)^k\mathcal{F}[T]$ (with the minus sign in front of the $i$). Where is the mistake?

2. Compute the F.T. of $D^k\mathcal{F}[T]$, where $D^k$ is the $k$-th derivative. As before $\phi(x)$ is a function of $x$ and $\hat\phi(y)$ is a funcion of $y$.
   My calculations are:
   $$
   \begin{align}
   (D^k\mathcal{F}[T])[\phi]&=D^k(\mathcal{F}[T])[\phi]\\
   &=(-1)^k(\mathcal{F}[T])\left[\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^k\phi\right]\\
   &=(-1)^kT\left[\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^k\phi\right]
   \end{align}
   $$
   Like before i used the properties for the derivative inside the F.T.,
   $$
   \begin{align}
   (-1)^kT\left[\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^k\phi\right]&=(-1)^kT\left[(-iy)^k\mathcal{F}[\phi]\right]\\
   &=(-1)^kT\left[\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^k\phi\right]\\
   &=(iy)^kT\left[\mathcal{F}[\phi]\right]=\mathcal{F}[(iy)^kT][\phi]
   \end{align}
   $$
   I'm not so sure about the last equality. I used $T_1 = ((iy)^kT)$ and $T_1[\mathcal{F}[\phi]] = \mathcal{F}[T_1][\phi]$ is that even a thing?

Also there are other things that confuse me:

3. When i have $(FD^kT)$ and I want to apply it to a function, do I write this $(FD^kT)[\phi]$ or this $FD^k(T[\phi])$? What is the correct order of computation?
4. Is it correct to say $(FD^kT)=F(D^kT)=(-iy)^kF(T)$?

Thanks in advance for any response, also pls correct any grammar mistakes, I'm not mother tongue :)

Comment: Thanks for the interesting questions! There are a few votes to close your post because you asked four questions and not only one. Could you please split the four questions into four posts (to stay in line with the guidelines)? Thanks!